# Fail to install tcpdump package in UBI8 (Read hat Universal Base Image)

Tags: dockerfile, tcpdump, ubi

I am building a docker image based on UBI8(Read hat Universal Base Image), Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal

RUN microdnf install sudo zip tar bash procps openssl iptables net-tools tcpdump && microdnf update; microdnf clean all

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/tcpdump" ]
```

But it failed to install tcpdump package.

```
Downloading metadata...
error: No package matches 'tcpdump'

(process:57): librhsm-WARNING **: 22:03:51.398: Found 0 entitlement certificates

(process:57): librhsm-WARNING **: 22:03:51.400: Found 0 entitlement certificates

(process:57): libdnf-WARNING **: 22:03:51.400: Loading "/etc/dnf/dnf.conf": IniParser: Can't open file
```

How to fix it in order to install a tcpdump package in UBI? Thanks.